# How to set Font Style in a TextMate 2 theme?

Tags: fonts, themes, textmate2

I would like to do this:

`settings = {
   fontStyle = 'italic';
   foreground = '#E5A472'; };
},`

But the font style is not changed.

What is the correct syntax to change font styles in a TextMate 2 theme?

I made changes to get to this:

`{ name = 'Markdown Italic';
      scope = 'markup.italic';
      settings = {
         fontStyle = 'italic';
         foreground = '#E5A472'; 
      };
 },`

But no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope selector is actually `markup.italic.markdown` not `markup.italic`.

```
   {    name = 'Markdown Italic';
        scope = 'markup.italic.markdown';
        settings = {
            fontStyle = 'italic';
            foreground = '#E5A472';
        };
    },
```

This was originally hidden by my font not having italics at all. So ensure that your font has a Italic face.

Comment: No, dang it. That didn't help. :(

Comment: If you post your theme, a gist or whatever is fine, I'd take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Graham, here's the Gist: https://gist.github.com/bobrocke/2b215834565770fcd92c

Comment: Updated answer @BobRockefeller, what do you think?

Comment: That didn't fix it. Nor did changing fontStyle to the proper font-style.

Comment: Using your gist, but changing just the selector worked for me. Did you try a common font, like Verdana?

Comment: Yes, Graham, that was it. Apparently TextMate 2 won't force "fake" italics or bold when the font doesn't come with real italics and bold. Such as Source Code Pro. Maybe that's a reason to switch to Menlo. Thanks!

Comment: [Source Code Pro Italics (beta) by davidpmccormick](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/1.002-it) This comes from [Source Code Pro's Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/issues/6)